# How to programmatically set the file icon on OS X?

Tags: macos, qt, qt5

Starting with an image - either a `QImage` or `QPixmap`, how to set it as a finder icon on a given file? Manually you can do it by dragging the image into the Get Info pane for any file. Presumably the icon is kept in a resource fork for that file.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete example. When ran, it asks you for a file to change the icon of, and then sets the icon to a yellow circle with blue outline.

#### main.mm

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/file-icon-set-38486934
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtMacExtras>
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>

QPixmap circle() {
   QPixmap pix{128, 128};
   pix.fill(Qt::transparent);
   QPainter p{&pix};
   p.setBrush(Qt::yellow);
   p.setPen(QPen{Qt::blue, 3});
   p.drawEllipse(pix.rect());
   return pix;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   auto path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(nullptr, "Select File");
   if (! path.isEmpty()) {
      auto image = QtMac::toNSImage(circle());
      auto filePath = path.toNSString();
      [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:image forFile:filePath options:0];
      [filePath release];
      [image release];
   }
   return 0;
}
```

#### file-icon-set-3846934.pro

```
QT = widgets macextras
CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = file-icon-set-38486934
TEMPLATE = app
OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += main.mm
LIBS += -framework AppKit
```